# What would I need to worry about in relation to developing software for intel64 vs amd64?

Tags: x86, 64-bit, x86-64

I was thinking about developing some low level software and was wondering if there are major issues developers get into when developing software for intel64 vs. amd64 architectures?

Some people mention that slight variations between them, but for most use cases they are cross-compatible. When would I need to worry about these differences? (wiki says compiler/os development, but what would I need to look out for?)

Comment: Are you doing compiler or OS development?

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Differences_between_AMD64_and_Intel_64